# How to stop re fetching of data in JFace TableViewer during column sorting

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have a TableViewer where in i'm setting the data through ContentProvider and LabelProvider i.e

```
tableViewer.setContentProvider(new SampleTableContentProvider());
tableViewer.setLabelProvider(new SampleTableLabelProvider());
tableViewer.setInput(parent);
```

I have overriden the getElements() of TableContentProvider to get the children to be stored in the table based on the parent set.

I have sorting the data by overriding doCompare() of ViewerComparator class.

So when i press the table column Header to sort a column , the getElements() of SampleTableContentProvider gets called again which is taking a lot of time to re fetch the data.

Is there any way to avoid this refetching of data while sorting table columns?

Comment: Show us `SampleTableContentProvider `, but I imagine you'd just cache it there and only retrieve the values if they're currently null?

Comment: @EvanKnowles I have tried this option, the values which i have stored in SampleTableContentProvider are always null.

Comment: @EvanKnowles SampleTableContentProvider implements IStructuredContentProvider. I have only overriden getElements() method to get the children.

Comment: And how do you get those elements?

Comment: @EvanKnowles I get the elements from the database based on the parent passed through setInput() method.

Comment: Code would be a lot faster here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80570/discussion-between-user1168608-and-evan-knowles).

Comment: @EvanKnowles But the data which i have to fetch from database is very huge. On an avaerage i would have 5000 rows with 20 columns